# How to trigger an application in mobile automatically

Tags: java-me

My idea is to make an application start automatically when a message from a specific user reaches the inbox of the mobile . For example if my friend sends some numbers to my mobile, the sms has to be read and validated first and then calculator ( inbuilt mobile application) has to be triggered and process the numbers from the message. Please help me with the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am far from convinced you will be able to give the phone user access to the same sms you use to launch your MIDlet.

You may need to use native development on the phones that support it if J2ME can't give you exactly what you need.

In any case, you probably want to try with J2ME first so you need to read the specifications for [JSR-118](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=118) and its `PushRegistry` API, along with [JSR-120](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=120), which interfaces with SMS.

Most current J2ME-enabled phones will support static SMS Push but you will need to send the SMS to a particular port, much like you would data over a standard library socket.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can trigger on just any old SMS message arriving.

This is the class you want to look at, in any case:

```
javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry
```